# Simplify, expressing answers in terms of powers of primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

So I'm not really sure how to express these two expressions in terms of powers of primes. Help?

$16\cdot25\cdot5^2$

and

$24^5$

Comment: Using $a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}, 16\cdot 25\cdot 5^2=2^4\cdot5^2\cdot5^2=2^4\cdot5^{2+2}.$ Try $24^5$

Comment: $16\times25\times5^2=2^4\times5^2\times5^2=2^4\times5^4$ and $24^5=(2^3\times3)^5=2^{15}\times3^5$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$16=2^4$$

$$25=5^2$$

$$24=3\cdot{2^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. $16 \times 25 \times 5^2 = 2^4 \times 5^2 \times 5^2 = 2^4 \times 5^{2+2} = 2^45^4$

and

2.$24^5=(8 \times 3)^5 = 8^5 \times 3^5 = (2^3)^5 \times 3^5=2^{3\times 5}\times 3^5=2^{15}3^5$

Answer (score 0):

$$16\cdot25\cdot 5^2=2^4\cdot5^2\cdot5^2=2^4\cdot5^4$$
and
$$24^5=(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3)^5=(2^3\cdot3)^5=2^{15}\cdot3^5$$

Comment: Maybe you want to replace $\Rightarrow$ with $=$?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer is it okay?

Comment: Looks better now.